# My R class is still referenced by com.example.myapp.R after renaming the package. How do I fix that?

Tags: android, adt

I started my project off as an example project, so it began as com.example.myapp.  I renamed everything so it's com.mycompany.myapp

But for some reason I still have to import the R class as com.example.myapp.R

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on the package hose name you want to change
2. Select *REFACTOR*
3. Rename
4. Check all options
5. Ok

Answer (score 0):

Go over to your manifest and change the package name as well,save and clean the project.If you are using android studio change the applicationId to your new package name and resync as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you renamed the package name in AndroidManifest.xml (it's usually the first line in the manifest). Once you've done that, clean the project by clicking **Project -> Clean...** in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Go over to your manifest and change the package name as well,save and clean the project.If you are using android studio go over to your build.gradle file and change the applicationId to your new package name and resync as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you pressed Alt+Shift+R(ename) to refactor/rename?

Best way to get sure all unnecessary references are deleted: Delete your generated R-Java file and rebuild project.